# Push from CI to private docker registry behind cloudflared with gated access through SSO

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, cloudflare

I have a portainer, that is running a registry and a cloudflared tunnel. The portainer web UI is secured by cloudflare zero trust tunnel. So this setup works. Now I want to deploy software I build onto the registry so I can deploy it. When I run a CI it should build a docker image and push it onto the registry. I expose the registry via HTTP through a zero trust tunnel.

Now how would I have a CI push there? I need to pass the zero trust SSO check. It seems like I have two options. Run cloudflared or warp in the CI. cloudflared tunnel seems not to be a VPN. As soon as I add a new cloudflared runner it will break the portainer web UI as the second one cannot solve it that way. Using warp I do have warp-cli register which just gives me a random account, when checked with warp-cli account. I do not see a way to connect my cloudflare account with the warp-cli session. I also checked with curl -s https://www.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/trace | grep -ie warp whether warp is enabled.

I am pretty new to cloudflare zero trust and I just want to try this out. I tried to read through the cloudflare documentation for cloudflared and WARP. WARP seems to work authenticated interactively but I did not get this working either. I got disappointed by GPT4 because it repeatedly suggested options, that warp-cli cannot do. It is totally fine, if the answer is: this is not how it supposed to work or similar. I am also fine with suggestions like a SSH server to hop through (best if I can run it in portainer and what would be a good way to expose it with cloudflare zero trust).